# How to trace what is wrong with my Ldap?

Tags: php, codeigniter, ldap

i need help. I am developing application for security. Here i am using ldap data to log in to the application. It actually work very well on my local. But when i try to upload them into my office server, so that everyone could access my application through the link. But it didnt work on my server it always been error 500, whenever i try to log on. Doesnt anyone has idea? the best way to trace them. i also have tried to check their configuration, it was find. Ldap has already provided in server.

Answer (score 0):

Let me first state that your question is not in line with Stacks guidelines and I'm not answering it per se. I am instead providing a means for you to debug further as a 500 isn't useful information.

In `index.php` change switch case to the following and upload to your server:

```
switch (ENVIRONMENT) {
    case 'development':
        error_reporting(~E_DEPRECATED);
        ini_set('display_errors', 1);
        break;
    case 'testing':
    case 'production':
        error_reporting(~E_DEPRECATED);
        ini_set('display_errors', 1);
        break;
    default:
        header('HTTP/1.1 503 Service Unavailable.', TRUE, 503);
        echo 'The application environment is not set correctly.';
        exit(1); // EXIT_ERROR
}
```

In your production `database.php` file change `db_debug` to `TRUE`. Upload the file to the server.

Your error should now be apparent.